# Аутентификация через сайт госуслуг. Как настроить свой механизм?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2

Нужно настроить аутентификацию через сайт гос-услуг. По идее тут хватило бы обычного

```
services.AddAuthentication().AddOAuth(...)
```

но для для этого требуется в опциях указать ClientSecret, а для гос услуг он должен формироваться динамически (зависит от даты). Как быть в данном случае? Как настроить свой механизм аутентификации предусмотрев динамическое формирование запроса?